# JSON being sent from Main Electron process coming over as undefined in the renderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios, electron

I am currently working on an Electron project to get my feet wet with the tech.  So far I've found it very interesting and fun to play with, I'm building a little home controller for my IoT devices, and though it is rudimentary, I'm running into a little problem right now.  I have a function in main.js that is making a request to my Philips Hue Bridge device to get a list of all of the lights it has connected to it.  I'm using the following function:

```js
function refreshLight() {
  console.log('Searching for lights');
  const HEADER = {
    'hue-application-key': `${HUE_KEY}`,
    'Content-type': 'text/plain'
  };

  const URL = `https://${HUE_IP}/clip/v2/resource/device`;

  axios.get(URL, {
    headers: HEADER,
    httpsAgent: agent
  })
    .then((response) => {
      const lights = [];
      for (const item of response.data.data) {
        for (const service of item.services) {
          if (service.rtype === 'light') {
            const light = {
              rid: service.rid,
              name: item.metadata.name,
              id_v1: item.id_v1
            };
            lights.push(light);
          }
        }
      }
      const jsonData = JSON.stringify(lights);
      mainWindow.webContents.send('lights-data', jsonData);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
}
```

The request fires of when the **renderer.js** function happens, and from **main.js** I get the JSON object back with what I'm expecting, however, when I try to receive it on the **renderer.js** side of things with the following:

```js
ipcRenderer.on('lights-data', (event, jsonData) => {
  console.log('Trying to display data');
  console.log(jsonData);
});
```

This is the preload:

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', {
  send: (channel, data) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, data),
  on: (channel, func) => ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))
});
```

And this is what I'm getting back:

[image]

Any assistance or pointers would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: odd. Though you shouldn't have to stringify stuff you pass to the renderer. Electron will serialize everything for you.

Comment: you've set a breakpoint here to confirm it's valid data? `const jsonData = JSON.stringify(lights);` (oh I guess you mention the JSON is valid in your question)

Comment: Can you please add your `preload.js` script to your question so we have a better understanding of your particular IPC mechanics.

Comment: Here is the preload.js:

`const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', {
    send: (channel, data) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, data),
    on: (channel, func) => ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))
});`

Answer (score 0):

The preload you shared shows that your `on` function do not pass the `event` to the callback. You are getting `undefined` because you are not logging the correct parameter. This should work:

```
ipcRenderer.on('lights-data', (jsonData) => {
  console.log('Trying to display data');
  console.log(jsonData);
});
```